# async pipe and button does not get appear until you click on tab manually

Tags: angular

I have below HTML code which is part of angular 6 application.

```
 <footer *ngIf="tab === 'toBeProcessed' && toBeProcessed | async as tobeprocessed">
        <custom-loader-button *ngIf="tobeprocessed['@count'] > 5" (click)="loadMoreOrders()" [showSpinner]="loader">
            {{ 'i18n.WID_GEN_loadMore' | translate | uppercase }}
        </custom-loader-button>

</footer>
```

I have tab table under which this button is defined, the above code works only when I click on tab manually or I switch between two tabs.

I have below code to make sure it detect changes.

I also tried putting below code:

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
            this.cd.detectChanges();
        }
```

Comment: What's your question? Can you post all relevant code

Comment: Can you please create a stackblitz for your issue ?